Regression testing for ROS stack
I have a complex ROS2 (Humble) application to get ready for production. We already unit test each node but that covers 5% of the global application.
I want to set up an automatic regression test routine that kicks off every time there is a new release.
I'm sure at some point we will have hundreds of tests. I'm not just looking at simple unit tests, but more complex "behavioral" tests. For example, when a sensor measurement becomes stale (sensor error for example) we need to stop the current task and broadcast a message to the other systems that something is wrong with that robot.
What is a good approach to implementing regression testing?
I understand that this is a fairly general question, but a general answer will be more than enough. Mostly looking at general ideas or pointers so that I can investigate more.
Thank you
